# how do i set countdown timer in node js and render it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am currently developing an auction website using Nodejs and react. For each bidding product, I want to display a countdown timer indicating the end of auction. I could not implement it in react because the timer just resets every time the user refreshes the website, or visits another page. I would like to count down the time for each product in backend(Nodejs) and somehow render it in react. How will that be possible?

Comment: You could register an expiry time using Date.now() on your Node.js server and have the React page look up the expiry time and count down from there.

Comment: @RichardAvenia but the timer will just restart from the starting time when the page is refreshed or reloaded right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the date time of your auction start should come from the DB and then the front end timer should start from there, rather than giving the authroization of the timer start time to front end

so you have the acution start time and calculate the timer based on that.

Let's say the auction start time is `start_time`
and let's say the current time is `current_time`

so `current_time - start_time` gives you how many seconds/minute has passed till the auction started.

and let's say the auction  time is `auction_time`. So basically you could simply write `auction_time - (current_time - start_time)` to give you a counter value

Comment: but the timer will just restart from the starting time when the page is refreshed or reloaded right?

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: this was a really good answer. i was leaning towards somehow, implementing socket for countdown timer but turns out it is really simple and efficient. thanks for the reply.

Comment: if you find it useful upvote so the other people can use it as well